# Value sent from Arduino being wrongly interpreted by C++

Tags: c++, casting, arduino, serial-port, double

I am having issues reading values calculated on my Arduino on my PC when I send raw binary date over serial.

I send the raw memory data of the `double` stored on the Aurdino. It is then sent over serial to my PC where another process reads the data from the serial input and loads it into a memory buffer which is then written to a double.

However, this produces weird results. While, the numbers do seem to be following a linear pattern as I'd expect (using a temperature sensor, the values get higher when I touch the sensor, and drop when I let go) but the values themselves are way off.

While, on the Arduino, I might get something like `21.32C` (room temp), on my PC I get a result similar to `1.68075e+08C`.

Here is the code I'm running on the Arduino:

```c
#define TEMP_PIN A0
#include <math.h>

void setup() {
  
  Serial.begin(9600);

}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
    int val;
    double temp;
    val = analogRead(TEMP_PIN);
  
    temp = log(((10240000/val) - 10000));
    temp = 1 / (0.001129148 + (0.000234125 + (0.0000000876741 * temp * temp ))* temp );
    temp -= 273.15;

    char out_buff[sizeof(double)];
    memcpy((void *) &out_buff, (void *) &temp, sizeof(double));
    
    Serial.write((byte *) &out_buff, sizeof(double));
    
    delay(0);
}
```

However, when I read the data into my computer, I get some weird results.

Here is the setup code for reading the serial interface:

```cpp
int USB = open("/dev/ttyACM0", O_RDWR| O_NOCTTY);
    
    struct termios tty;
    struct termios tty_old;
    memset (&tty, 0, sizeof tty);

    /* Error Handling */
    if ( tcgetattr ( USB, &tty ) != 0 ) {
    std::cout << "Error " << errno << " from tcgetattr: " << strerror(errno) << std::endl;
    }

    /* Save old tty parameters */
    tty_old = tty;

    /* Set Baud Rate */
    cfsetospeed (&tty, (speed_t)B9600);
    cfsetispeed (&tty, (speed_t)B9600);

    /* Setting other Port Stuff */
    tty.c_cflag     &=  ~PARENB;            // Make 8n1
    tty.c_cflag     &=  ~CSTOPB;
    tty.c_cflag     &=  ~CSIZE;
    tty.c_cflag     |=  CS8;

    tty.c_cflag     &=  ~CRTSCTS;           // no flow control
    tty.c_cc[VMIN]   =  1;                  // read doesn't block
    tty.c_cc[VTIME]  =  5;                  // 0.5 seconds read timeout
    tty.c_cflag     |=  CREAD | CLOCAL;     // turn on READ & ignore ctrl lines

    /* Make raw */
    cfmakeraw(&tty);

    /* Flush Port, then applies attributes */
    tcflush( USB, TCIFLUSH );
    if ( tcsetattr ( USB, TCSANOW, &tty ) != 0) {
    std::cout << "Error " << errno << " from tcsetattr" << std::endl;
    }
```

And finally, here is the code I used to read the data into the buffer and interoperate it:

```cpp
    char response_buffer[sizeof(double)];
    char byte_buffer = '\0';
    memset(response_buffer, '\0', sizeof(double));
    
    for (int i = 0; i < (sizeof(double)); i += 1) {
        read(USB, &byte_buffer, 1);
        response_buffer[i] = byte_buffer;
        printf("%d\n", byte_buffer);
    }

    double arduino_value = 0.0d;
    memcpy((void *) &arduino_value, (void *) &response_buffer, (int) (sizeof(double)));

    cout << "Value: " << arduino_value << endl;
```

This produces the following result:

```
-64
-95
-94
65
-64
-95
-94
65
Value: 1.56295e+08
```

You can see that each byte is repeated twice. This is leading me to believe that there is a discrepancy in the way the Arduino handles doubles and the way G++ handles doubles.

Perhaps a double on the Arduino is only 4 bytes? If so, then how can I read it correctly in G++ compiled C++?

Comment: *It is then sent over serial to my PC* -- Anything to do with [endianness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness)?  You also didn't show the output that Arduino has, in bytes, similar to what you did for the PC.

Comment: Your question about the size of a double suggests you haven't read the datasheet for your part, and about the compiler you're using to compile your Arduino code. If you won't do that, and don't *know* the bytes going across, then you are not informed.

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing is fundamentally not going to work -- the platforms have different endiannes, but also floating point representation in C++ is somewhat flexible.

For instance: On Arduino UNO float and double are both 32bit types, while on DUE float is 32bit and double is 64bit. See https://forum.arduino.cc/t/double-to-byte-array/536394/5

Your approach has a lot of other issues, for instance you are not sending start/stop markers and have no way to tell if the stream was started in the middle, e.g the first byte missed. Then all the numbers would be completely wrong.

An easy fix is to print and parse the values instead, ie.

```
//on arduino: 
float my_val = 3.5234234; 
Serial.println(my_val); 

//on the pc: (roughly...)
string line = get_line_from_serial(); //magic!
float my_val; 
sscanf(line.c_str(), "%f", my_val);
```

This is also hacky and a bit of a resource waste, but it might take you far enough and (imho) isn't too bad.

A solution I'm using myself is to use HDLC (or similar) as transport protocol, and BINN (or similar) for data encoding. It might sound overly complicated, but data transmission between completely different architectures is in fact complex.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/High-Level_Data_Link_Control

https://github.com/mengguang/minihdlc

https://github.com/liteserver/binn